# Angular unit testing - How can I get the child component inside an overlay container

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-test

I have a custom component called `MatSelectControls` that is used like so:

```
<component-im-testing>
   <mat-select>
      <mat-select-controls></mat-select-controls>
      <mat-option *ngFor="..."></mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</component-im-testing>
```

In my test, I can retrieve the `MatSelect` instance like so:

```
const matSelectRef = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatSelect));
const matSelect = matSelectRef.componentInstance as MatSelect;
matSelect.open();
```

But what I'm really after is the `MatSelectControls` component. Trying to select it the same way does not work:

```
const matControlsRef = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatSelectControls)); //returns null
```

I'm assuming this doesn't work because the `MatSelectControls` actually renders inside of the cdk overlay that `MatSelect` creates.

How can I retrieve the `MatSelectControls` component instance even though it actually renders inside the cdk overlay?

Answer (score 0):

Without the complete code it is difficult to help, but what you could do is simply add a reference to the `mat-select-controls` component via `@ViewChild()` in your parent component:

```
@ViewChild(MatSelectControls) matSelectControls: MatSelectControls;
```

And then use it in your test:

```
component.matSelectControls.abc
```

Comment: problem for me here is: how can I know the moment that matSelectControls becomes defined

Comment: Something like this `fixture.detectChanges(); fixture.whenStable().then(() => { /* code here */ }`.